# Searching through an Excel Sheet and Printing Data in Python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to use Python to search through and Excel file and print data that corresponds to the value of a cell that the user searched for.

I have an Excel File with a list of every Zip Code in the USA in one column and the next four columns are information related to that Zip Code such as the state it is located in, the price to ship an object there, and so on. I would like the user to be able to search for a specific zip code and have the program print out the information in the corresponding cells.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

book = open_workbook('zip_code_database edited.xls',on_demand=True)
prompt = '>'
print "Please enter a Zip Code."
item = raw_input(prompt)
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for cell in sheet.col(1): #
    if sheet.cell_value == item:
        print "Data: ",sheet.row
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a specific question? What did you expect your code to do? What did it actually do? Have you attempted to debug by running through the code line by line manually?

Answer (score 0):

`sheet.cell_value` is a function it will never be equal to `item`. You should try accessing using `cell.value`

Example -

```
for cell in sheet.col(1): 
    if cell.value == item:
        print "Data: ",cell
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with the module `xlrd` that you are using, but it seems like you could maybe make this easier on yourself if you just use a regular python `dictionary` for this job and create a small module containing the loaded dictionary. I'm assuming you are familiar with the python `dictionary` for the following solution.

You will use the zip codes as keys and the other 4 data fields as values for the dictionary (I'm assuming a `.csv` file below but you could also use tab-delimited or other single spaces). Call the following file `make_zip_dict.py`:

```
zipcode_dict = {}
myzipcode = 'zip_code_database edited.xls'

with open(myzipcode, 'r') as f:

    for line in f:

        line     = line.split(',')  # break the line into the 5 fields
        zip_code = line[0] # assuming zips are the first column 
        info     = ' '.join(line[1:])  # the other fields turned into a string with single spaces

        # now for each zip, enter the info in the dictionary:
        zipcode_dict[zip_code] = info
```

Save this file to the same directory as `'zip_code_database edited.xls'`. Now, to use it interactively, navigate to the directory and start a python interactive session:

```
>>> import make_zip_dict as mzd  # this loads the module and the dict
>>> my_zip = '10001'  # pick some zip to try out
>>> mzd.zipcode_dict[my_zip]  # enter it into the dict
'New York City NY $9.99 info4'  # it should return your results
```

You can just work with this interactively on the command line by entering your desired zip code. There are some fancy bells and whistles you could add too, but this will very quickly spit out the info and it should be pretty lightweight and quick.